# android player plays about 30 times and stops

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, multiple-instances

The following plays for about 30 consecutive times, and then stops playing audio.  (The program continues to run.)  I have read that I may be creating too many instances of the player.  How can I modify this code to prevent that?
(This code has been edited using suggestions and is still playing only about 30 times.)

```
public static MediaPlayer m;
private void playboopboop(String fileName) {
    try {
        AssetFileDescriptor d = getAssets().openFd(fileName);
        long start = d.getStartOffset();
        long end = d.getLength();
        this.m = new MediaPlayer();
        this.m.setDataSource(d.getFileDescriptor(), start, end);
        this.m.setLooping(false);
        this.m.prepare();
        this.m.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        doalert("Audio Error: " + e);
    }
}
```

Comment: You create one MediaPlayer once elsewhere in the Activity, and play all the media on that one.

Comment: Is it playing multiple times in a row or all at once?

Comment: Make sure to set looping to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reset method will stop any media and send the MediaPlayer instance back to the idle state, in the same state when it was created.  The working code is as follows:

```
public MediaPlayer m = new MediaPlayer();
private void playboopboop(String fileName) {
    try {
        AssetFileDescriptor d = getAssets().openFd(fileName);
        long start = d.getStartOffset();
        long end = d.getLength();
        m.reset(); // set player to initial creation state
        m.setDataSource(d.getFileDescriptor(), start, end);
        m.prepare();
        m.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        doalert("Audio Error: " + e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the media player outside of the function and pass it into the function as a variable or reference it if you are within the class. That will help you to not accidentally create too many instances. You should also set looping to false. If looping is true then as soon as the file finishes it will start again. For example:

```
private void playboopboop(String fileName, MediaPlayer m) {
    try {
        AssetFileDescriptor d = getAssets().openFd(fileName);
        long start = d.getStartOffset();
        long end = d.getLength();
        m.setDataSource(d.getFileDescriptor(), start, end);
        m.setLooping(false);
        m.prepare();
        m.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        doalert("Audio Error: " + e);
    }
}
```

Or like this:

```
//Defined in the class you are using
public MediaPlayer m = new MediaPlayer();

private void playboopboop(String fileName) {
    try {
        AssetFileDescriptor d = getAssets().openFd(fileName);
        long start = d.getStartOffset();
        long end = d.getLength();
        this.m.setDataSource(d.getFileDescriptor(), start, end);
        this.m.setLooping(false);
        this.m.prepare();
        this.m.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        doalert("Audio Error: " + e);
    }
}
```

Comment: the second example only plays once.

Comment: When I pass the player as an argument as in the first example, it plays once, then on the second attempt: "Illegal State Exception".

Comment: You probably have to reset the media player at the start of the function